# Google App Engine UserServiceget.CurrentUser() returns null in servlet handling channel connect at /_ah/channel/connected/

Tags: java, google-app-engine, channel-api

I use Google Channel api and registered servlet at adreess /_ah/channel/connected/ to handle user channel connects. When connection happens in post message handler I find out that UserServiceget.CurrentUser() returns null, while in other servlets of my application it returns user. What is the case tell me please. The servlet code is like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ConnectServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                    throws IOException {
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

        if( user != null ){        
        String user_name = user.getNickname();
        Logger.getLogger("server").log( Level.WARNING, "User " + user_name + "  connected" );
       }
    }
}
```

security-constraint is:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `/_ah/channel/connected/` is made by an internal Google Channel service server, not by user directly. So this request does not have user associated with it.

This is an [example how to handle Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview#Example_Tic_Tac_Toe_Application):

1. Server: Create a unique Client ID on the server. You can use user id:

   ```
   String clientId = userService.getCurrentUser().getUserId();
   ```
2. Server: Create channel token from the Client ID and pass it back to client side:

   ```
   ChannelService channelService = ChannelServiceFactory.getChannelService();
   String token = channelService.createChannel(clientId);
   ```
3. Use token in Javascript on client side:

   ```
   // --token-- a token received from server
   channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('--token--');
   ```
4. Then in `/_ah/channel/connected/` handler you can do:

   ```
   ChannelService channelService = ChannelServiceFactory.getChannelService();
   ChannelPresence presence = channelService.parsePresence(req);
   String clientId = presence.clientId();
   // clientId equals userId as set in point 1.
   ```

Comment: Oh thanks. Now I know client id of the user who connects. That's what I needed.

Comment: i would not recommend using Channels; https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/channel